# Sequelize and Jest not playing well together

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, jestjs

To be a bit more specific, I'm using Jest's `globalSetup` and `globalTeardown` functions/files to setup my database once at the start, and then also close and drop the tables at the end.

This isn't really the best solution, but sadly it's the only one that even remotely works without errors. Ideally, I would like to be able to establish the database connection once, and then drop/clear tables and re-create them after every test suite. Usually, with other databases (specifically Mongoose/NoSQL), this could be accomplished with Jest's `beforeAll/Each` and `afterAll/Each` no problem, but sadly this results in a lot of errors with Sequelize, specifically that it tries to re-establish the database connection every time which results in a lot of port/listen errors.

The reason I say my current setup of using the global files "sort of" works, is because the setup part works perfectly, but the teardown part, AKA `await db.dropAllSchemas({});` doesn't work at all. The tables are kept throughout all tests, unless I manually wipe them.

If someone has any experience with this, I would ideally like to achieve the solution I posted in the first part, but worst case I'd like to fix what I currently have so it drops tables at the end of all tests.

This is the code I'm using to try and achieve the FIRST solution (without global files), and which causes all the errors;
*setupTestFramework.js*

```
import { db } from '../../src/startup/database';

beforeAll(async () => {
  await db.sync();
});

afterAll(async () => {
  await db.dropAllSchemas({});
});
```

This code results in the errors;

```
SequelizeDatabaseError: Table 'db_tests.products' doesn't exist
```

It also results in a sort of scatter in the tests. Some of the initial tests pass (mainly 1–2 and probably because they are on the same DB connection), but after those all test fail.

Hopefully someone can help out as I've not really been able to find a decent solution to this.

EDIT:

database.js

```
import config from 'config';
import Sequelize from 'sequelize';
import { info } from 'winston';

export const db = new Sequelize(
  config.get('db.database'),
  config.get('db.username'),
  config.get('db.password'),
  {
    host: config.get('db.host'),
    port: config.get('db.port'),
    dialect: 'mysql',
    operatorsAliases: false,
    logging:
      process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' || process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test' ? null : console.log,
  }
);

export default async () => {
  try {
    await db.authenticate();
    info('Connected to database successfully...');

    await db.sync();
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error('Unable to connect to database...');
  }
};
```

Comment: Have you tried ditching async / await syntax and just returning the promise? e.g. `beforeAll(() => db.sync())`. All the teardown / setup functions should handle Promises so if there is an issue it most likely lies with your DB setup code.

Comment: @James Yeah already tried this, same issue. I'm actually not sure if my setup code is even working at all now, same as my teardown code. If I put console.log inside those funcs, they get printed, but if I use the Sequelize funcs inside, it's like they don't even run. For example, if I manually drop all the tables, and then run my tests, it complains the tables don't exist (even though my setup should have created/sync'd them), but then if I run again, it finds them. I'm thinking something fishy is going on here.

Comment: yeah as I say, sounds more to me like the issue lies with your code not working, as this type of thing would be a gaping bug with Jest and certainly would've been caught by now. If you post your setup code we can see what's going on.

Comment: @James Yeah that's what I figured. What code do you need exactly? My `globalSetup` and `globalTeardown`? My actual database setup file? My supertest setup? Let me know what you need and I'll edit it into the OP. :)

Comment: I'd say let's start with the imported file in the code example, you can omit any sensitive information if necessary

Comment: @James Updated OP with that files contents.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187176/discussion-between-james-and-borassign).

Answer (score 3):

I had an issue similar to yours, i fixed it by closing the db connection at the end of all tests.

Export your db in your database config file and import it in your test class, then you can close the connection at the end of all tests.

```
afterAll(() => {
    db.close()
})
```

Note: when you drop all schemas, it removes all tables (for postgres db), instead close the connection after each test suites.